# Visual Studio Breakpoint Bar Not Present (Glyph margin, Overview Ruler)

Tags: visual-studio

So I hit some weird combination of keystrokes, and now my visual studio looks all jacked up and I can't figure out how to customize it back to what it was. I've googled it lots, and I can't seem to find out where to fix it all.

It's just the code editor that's been bugging me for weeks. I figured some of you could probably help.

It looks like this:
[image: Visual Studio Code Window Messed Up]

I just want the dang lines in front of the code to go away, and to be able to click to the left of the numbered lines to get a breakpoint again.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Go to *Tools* → *Options* → *Text Editor* → *General*
2. Check *Indicator Margin*

[image]

I'm not sure what »dang lines in front of the code« you mean, though. If you're referring to the yellow *unsaved changes* indicator, that's the *Selection Margin* in the options above. If you mean the dots (representing spaces), then *Edit* → *Advanced* → *View White Space* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Whew! One down, one to go. Any idea how to get the lines before the code to go away? I've been exploring the text editor options and can't seem to find the right one. I'm so happy to have the breakpoint bar there again, though!

Comment: Ha! You're a genius. I always use ctrl+e+d to reformat code, and I must have hit e+s one of those times. Thanks Joey, it's been bothering me for weeks!

Answer (score 4):

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Indication Marker (For border breakpoints)
>
> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Line Numbers (For line numbers)

Comment: They didn't complain about the line numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the indication marker one, although joey just barely beat you to it.

Comment: Well I wasn't sure exactly what "dang lines in front of the code" are. If he was referring to the YELLOW LINES to the LEFT of the code he should have been more explicit.

Comment: No problem Ryan, glad I could help (albeit a bit late).

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know exactly what they were called or why it was even showing them, but it was as above, just the spaces being replaced by a bunch of --- was annoying.

Answer (score 3):

For **Visual Studio Code** (aka **VSCode**), and my years later 
 almost exact same question
(whereas I misinterpreted the 
 setting description),
I found my similar but different answer:

Enable it like following in **Settings** GUI:

> Editor: **Glyph Margin**
>    Controls whether the editor should render the vertical glyph margin.
>      Glyph margin is mostly used for debugging.

*Or* write equivalent to following in **settings.json**:

```js
  "editor.glyphMargin": true,
```